# How to allow calls to ring on Silent Mode from everyone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I always use my iPhone in silent mode and do not want any notification sounds except for calls. I would prefer that calls (from **anyone**) always rings, no matter if I am in Do Not Disturb mode or not. Since people only call me for very important things. Currently, I could set it up such that call notifications are displayed in the Do Not Disturb mode, but I cannot get the phone to actually ring so mostly I will just miss the call and notice it later as I don't check my phone often. Updated the phone to iOS 16.

Comment: This is a very important question, I miss calls, but same as OP I don't want any Notifications to ring a sound or vibrate, I just want any calls to ring and vibrate while on Silent because realistically you don't get too many calls in 2023, it's all notifications.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 15 [can't check 16 yet]

Settings > Focus > Do Not Disturb > People > Also allow Calls From > Everyone

Requires the phone is not set to silent mode with the side switch.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the phone cannot be set to silent mode (I do not want to myriad of sounds the phone makes while typing etc) and I have to set it do not disturb mode to get disturbed by calls, which doesn't make much sense if I want to see regular messages (but not hear them) as well

Comment: Typing noises are independently switchable. Use a different, manual focus mode if you also need DND for something else.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphb71f9b54d/ios#iphcc98fdd04) from Apple's iPhone User Guide for iOS 16 regarding the "**silent mode**" activated by the physical switch on the left side, clearly states that silent mode is just silent (and full stop):

> When silent mode is on, iPhone doesn’t ring or play alerts or other
> sound effects (but iPhone may still vibrate). Important: Clock alarms,
> audio apps such as Music, and many games play sounds through the
> built-in speaker, even when silent mode is on.

**However** there is an exception to this rule: iPhone WILL always ring for an incoming call if you customize the contact ringtone, regardless of silent mode or focus mode. To do that open the phone app > click a contact > click edit (upper right) > click ring tone or sms tone (right under email) > click "emergency exception" to turn ON.

Different story not to be confused with the "**do not disturb**" focus mode, for which [this other article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph21d43af5b/ios) of iOS 16 leaves the door open to allow calls or notifications from specific people during a Focus, or even wider audience from favs group, all contacts or anyone at all. Inside a focus mode 'persons' you can also define a general flag to allow repeated calls within 3 minutes to ring.